# Add recorddset to sql table

Tags: sql, vba, recordset

I have a recordset and I want to copy this in new table in sql using VB Script. new table should be created as per recordset only. Someone has examples?

I know how to create new table but how to copy entire recordset to this table. I have something like following code and my recordset is retrieved in oRs variable.

```
Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set oCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

oCom.CommandText = "my command text"

Set oRs = oCom.Execute
```

Kbv.

Comment: `Insert Into NewTablename (column, column1, etc) Select column, column1 From OldTablename`

Comment: My old table is encrypted and divided in many tables and using an external tool I am able to query data but it is retrieved in this recordset. Now I want to create another table from this recordset. I can create table manually or using script, but how do I insert recordset in new table.

Comment: It depends a little bit on your setup. If you have access to `BULK INSERT`, then I suppose the fastest way would be to create a `CSV` file and insert from that. Otherwise, you could add your extracted data one row at a time.